# How much Gleason type theorem do I need? Quasi states vs. states

Tags: measure-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, lattices, quantum-mechanics

Let $\varphi$ be a quasi state on $B(H)$. What does it mean? It means that $\varphi(cA)=c\varphi(A)$ for $c \in \mathbb{C}, A \in B(H)$, $\varphi(A) \geq 0$ for positive $A$ and $\varphi(A+B)=\varphi(A)+\varphi(B)$ provided that $AB=BA$. Does it follow that $\varphi$ is automatically linear? This problem is related to the so called Gleason type theorems. Let me cite first the

> **Classical Gleason Theorem** Let $\mu:P(H) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a completely additive measure on the lattice of all projections in $H$ (where $H$ is infinite dimensional) meaning that $\mu(\sum_s P_s)=\sum_s \mu(P_s) $ for an orthogonal family $(P_s)_s$. Then $\mu$ extends to a *normal* functional $\varphi$ on $B(H)$.

This theorem is valid also in finite dimension provided that we assume that $\mu$ is bounded. It is rather nontrivial fact that this boundedness assumption is superfluous when the dimension is infinite.

People were interested in generalization of this theorem: first of all one can require this theorem to work for more general lattices of projections (in general von Neumann algebras). Secondly, one can weaken the assumption of being completely additive (which is equivalent to countable additivity in separable $H$) and require $\mu$ to be only *finitely* additive. Let me ignore the case of more general vN algebra and formulate

> **The generalized Gleason Theorem**: Let $\mu:P(H) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded finitely additive measure on the lattice of all projections in $H$ meaning that $\mu(P+Q)=\mu(P)+\mu(Q) $ for mutually orthogonal projections $P,Q$. Then $\mu$ extends to a bounded linear functional $\varphi$ on $B(H)$.

Having these two theorems in mind I would like to ask the following:

> **Question** Let $\varphi$ be a quasi state on $B(H)$ (as defined above). How much ,,boundedness'' (or other assumptions?) do I have to assume in order to conclude that:  a) $\varphi$ is a (normal?) state using original Gleason Theorem
> b) $\varphi$ is a state using the generalized Gleason Theorem.
> Does the situation differ if we don't assume positivity?

My question is not one hundred percent precise which is due to the fact that the notion of quasi state/quasi linearity differs in the literature: sometimes one assume only that $\varphi(cA)=c\varphi(A)$ for *real* $c$, $\varphi(A+B)=\varphi(A)+\varphi(B)$ for commuting *self-adjoint* $A,B$ and $\varphi(A+iB)=\varphi(A)+i\varphi(B)$ for self adjoint $A,B$. We should also remember that we work in an apriori nonlinear seeting therefore boundedness need not imply continuity. I hope that despite my question is not completely precise one can shed some light on this issue.